# Efficient way to find repeated runs of rows, remove, & count

Tags: r

I have a data set with repeating rows.  I want to remove consecutive repeated and count them but only if they're consecutive.  I'm looking for an efficient way to do this.  Can't think of how in **dplyr** or **data.table**.

### MWE

```
dat <- data.frame(
    x = c(6, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4),
    y = c(7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 7, 1, 2, 7, 7, 1, 7),
    z = c(rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=7))
)

##        x     y     z
## 1      6     7     A
## 2      2     5     A
## 3      3     7     A
## 4      3     7     A
## 5      3     7     A
## 6      1     5     A
## 7      1     5     A
## 8      6     7     B
## 9      5     1     B
## 10     5     2     B
## 11     6     7     B
## 12     6     7     B
## 13     5     1     B
## 14     4     7     B
```

### Desired output

```
       x     y     z   n
1      6     7     A   1
2      2     5     A   1
3      3     7     A   3
4      1     5     A   2
5      6     7     B   1
6      5     1     B   1
7      5     2     B   1
8      6     7     B   2
9      5     1     B   1 
10     4     7     B   1
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)

dat[, c(.SD[1L], .N), by=.(g = rleidv(dat))][, g := NULL]

    x y z N
 1: 6 7 A 1
 2: 2 5 A 1
 3: 3 7 A 3
 4: 1 5 A 2
 5: 6 7 B 1
 6: 5 1 B 1
 7: 5 2 B 1
 8: 6 7 B 2
 9: 5 1 B 1
10: 4 7 B 1
```

Comment: Well played.  There are some handy tools in **data.table** I need to dive into deeper.

Comment: Something like this could be could for large data.tables:  `dat[, g := rleidv(dat)][, N := .N, keyby = g][J(unique(g)), mult = "first"][, g := NULL][]`

Comment: @Jota Yeah, that's what I'd do in practice; just went with this way because it's shorter / more direct. By the way, you don't need the `.()` wrapper if there's just one column.

Comment: So many great solutions.  but this was first and indeed fast.

Comment: I really tore into this code and used the data.table cheat sheet to understand it: https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf  On thing I still am not getting...Why do you need `c()`  Why not `.()`?  I.e., when do I use `c` vs. `.`?

Comment: @Tyler `.()` is an alias for `list()` so that would give `list(.N, .SD)`, but `.SD` is already a list and we want the result to be a one-level list (instead of nested). I think there might be a feature request for `.(col, .SD)` and I've certainly typed it mistakenly many times.

Answer (score 15):

Similar to Ricky's answer, here's another base solution:

```
with(rle(do.call(paste, dat)), cbind(dat[ cumsum(lengths), ], lengths))
```

In case `paste` doesn't cut it for the column classes you have, you can do

```
ud     = unique(dat)
ud$r   = seq_len(nrow(ud))
dat$r0 = seq_len(nrow(dat))
newdat = merge(dat, ud)

with(rle(newdat[order(newdat$r0), ]$r), cbind(dat[cumsum(lengths), ], lengths))
```

... though I'm guessing there's some better way.

Comment: *In case paste doesn't cut it* I see what you did there.

Answer (score 11):

With `dplyr`, you can borrow `data.table::rleid` to make a run ID column, then use `n` to count rows and `unique` to chop out repeats:

```
dat %>% group_by(run = data.table::rleid(x, y, z)) %>%  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
    distinct() %>% ungroup() %>% select(-run)
```

You can replace `rleid` with just base R, if you like, but it's not as pretty:

```
dat %>% group_by(run = rep(seq_along(rle(paste(x, y, z))$len), 
                           times = rle(paste(x, y, z))$len)) %>%  
    mutate(n = n()) %>% distinct() %>% ungroup() %>% select(-run)
```

Either way, you get:

```
Source: local data frame [10 x 4]

       x     y      z     n
   (dbl) (dbl) (fctr) (int)
1      6     7      A     1
2      2     5      A     1
3      3     7      A     3
4      1     5      A     2
5      6     7      B     1
6      5     1      B     1
7      5     2      B     1
8      6     7      B     2
9      5     1      B     1
10     4     7      B     1
```

---

#### Edit

Per @Frank's comment, you can also use `summarise` to insert `n` and collapse instead of `mutate` and `unique` if you `group_by` all the variables you want to keep *before `run`*, as `summarise` collapses the *last* group. One advantage to this approach is that you don't have to `ungroup` to get rid of `run`, as `summarise` does for you:

```
dat %>% group_by(x, y, z, run = data.table::rleid(x, y, z)) %>% 
    summarise(n = n()) %>% select(-run)
```

Comment: Isn't `mutate(n()) %>% distinct` the same as `summarise(n())`?

Comment: @Frank Not quite; `summarise(n())` would just leave you with a single column unless you had grouped by or included everything else: `summarise(x = unique(x), y = unique(y), z = unique(y), n = n())` would be equivalent.

Answer (score 10):

A base solution below

```
idx <- rle(with(dat, paste(x, y, z)))
d <- cbind(do.call(rbind, strsplit(idx$values, " ")), idx$lengths)
as.data.frame(d)  

   V1 V2 V3 V4
1   6  7  A  1
2   2  5  A  1
3   3  7  A  3
4   1  5  A  2
5   6  7  B  1
6   5  1  B  1
7   5  2  B  1
8   6  7  B  2
9   5  1  B  1
10  4  7  B  1
```

Comment: Or `with(rle(do.call(paste, dat)), cbind(dat[ cumsum(lengths), ], lengths))`. Also strsplit will give you strings or factors, while you probably want numbers in some cols.

Comment: That's brilliant Frank, I'd vote for that if you put it as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a large dataset, you could use a similar idea to Frank's data.table solution, but avoid using `.SD` like this:

```
dat[, g := rleidv(dat)][, N := .N, keyby = g
   ][J(unique(g)), mult = "first"
   ][, g := NULL
   ][]
```

It's less readable, and it turns out it's slower, too.  Frank's solution is faster and more readable.

```
# benchmark on 14 million rows
dat <- data.frame(
    x = rep(c(6, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4), 1e6),
    y = rep(c(7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 7, 1, 2, 7, 7, 1, 7), 1e6),
    z = rep(c(rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=7)), 1e6)
)

setDT(dat)
d1 <- copy(dat)
d2 <- copy(dat)
```

With R 3.2.4 and data.table 1.9.7 (on Frank's computer):

```
system.time(d1[, c(.SD[1L], .N), by=.(g = rleidv(d1))][, g := NULL])
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.42    0.10    0.52 
system.time(d2[, g := rleidv(d2)][, N := .N, keyby = g][J(unique(g)), mult = "first"][, g := NULL][])
#    user  system elapsed 
#    2.48    0.25    2.74
```

Comment: Your first code block makes reference to `d2`, but I guess you want only dat there. Also, I see different timings, actually with mine 5x as fast... odd.

Comment: 3.2.3 and 1.9.7 here. Yours is about the same if I write it like `system.time(d2[, g := rleidv(.SD)][, c(.N, .SD[1L]), by=g][, g := NULL][])`. I think the difference may be that `.SD[1L]` was optimized recently. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/735

Comment: @Frank there was a problem with my data.table installation and the datatable.dll.  After fixing it, I'm getting results similar to your timings.

Comment: @Frank, right on. It was optimised. An easy way to test it is by adding `verbose = TRUE` to the `[]` call, e.g., `dat[, c(.SD[1L], .N), by=.(g = rleidv(dat)), verbose=TRUE]`

Answer (score 7):

Not much different than the other answers, but (1) having ordered data and (2) looking for consecutive runs seems a good candidate for, just, `OR`ing `x[-1L] != x[-length(x)]` accross columns instead of `paste`ing or other complex operations. I guess this is, somehow, equivalent to `data.table::rleid`.

```
ans = logical(nrow(dat) - 1L)
for(j in seq_along(dat)) ans[dat[[j]][-1L] != dat[[j]][-nrow(dat)]] = TRUE    
ans = c(TRUE, ans)
#or, the two-pass, `c(TRUE, Reduce("|", lapply(dat, function(x) x[-1L] != x[-length(x)])))`

cbind(dat[ans, ], n = tabulate(cumsum(ans)))
#   x y z n
#1  6 7 A 1
#2  2 5 A 1
#3  3 7 A 3
#6  1 5 A 2
#8  6 7 B 1
#9  5 1 B 1
#10 5 2 B 1
#11 6 7 B 2
#13 5 1 B 1
#14 4 7 B 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Another base attempt using `ave`, just because:

```
dat$grp <- ave(
  seq_len(nrow(dat)),
  dat[c("x","y","z")],
  FUN=function(x) cumsum(c(1,diff(x))!=1)
)

dat$count <- ave(dat$grp, dat, FUN=length)

dat[!duplicated(dat[1:4]),]


#   x y z grp count
#1  6 7 A   0     1
#2  2 5 A   0     1
#3  3 7 A   0     3
#6  1 5 A   0     2
#8  6 7 B   0     1
#9  5 1 B   0     1
#10 5 2 B   0     1
#11 6 7 B   1     2
#13 5 1 B   1     1
#14 4 7 B   0     1
```

And a `data.table` conversion attempt:

```
d1[, .(sq=.I, grp=cumsum(c(1, diff(.I)) != 1)), by=list(x,y,z)][(sq), .N, by=list(x,y,z,grp)]
```